# How to compare the equality of values between columns without comparing NAs?

Tags: r

I want to compare whether any of the values matches between in the first row of the data frame. In return I want to get a 1 for TRUE and 0 for FALSE. I am only trying work on the first row because later on I want to write a for loop for all 1000 rows of the dataframe.

This is the first row that I am working with.

```
  illness_1 illness_2 illness_3 illness_4 illness_5 illness_6 illness_7
1      1065      1139        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA
  illness_8 illness_9 illness_10 illness_11 illness_12 illness_13 DC1 DC2 DC3
1        NA        NA         NA         NA         NA         NA  42  NA  NA
  DC4 DC5 DC6 DC7 DC8 DC9 DC10 DC11 DC12 DC13 DC14 DC15 DC16 DC17 DC18 DC19 DC20
1  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
  DC21 DC22 DC23 DC24 DC25 DC26 DC27 DC28 DC29 DC30 DC31 DC32 DC33 DC34 DC35
1   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
  DC36 DC37 DC38 DC39 DC40 DC41 DC42 DC43 DC44 DC45 DC46 DC47 DC48 DC49 DC50
1   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
  DC51 DC52 DC53 DC54 DC55 DC56 DC57 DC58 DC59 DC60 DC61 DC62 DC63 DC64 DC65
1   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
  DC66 DC67 DC68 DC69 DC70 DC71 DC72 DC73 DC74 DC75 DC76 DC77 DC78 DC79 DC80
1   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
  DC81 DC82 DC83 DC84 DC85 DC86 DC87 DC88 DC89 DC90 DC91 DC92 DC93 DC94 DC95
1   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
  DC96 DC97 DC98 DC99 DC100
1   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA
```

I have tried the following code.

```
ifelse(
  any(
    !is.na(dplyr::select(data_set, contains("illness")))
  ) ==
    any(
      !is.na(dplyr::select(data_set, contains("DC")))
    ), 1, 0
)
```

And it returned a 1, which I am expecting a 0.

Can any one help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to SO! That piece of code returns `1` if both `any()` calls return either `TRUE` ( there are any non-NA values in *illness* columns  AND any non-NA values in *DC* columns) OR both `any()` calls return `FALSE` ( there no non-NA values in *illness* columns  AND no non-NA values in *DC* columns ) . In the first row of dataset illness_1 , illness_2 & DC1 are non-NA, so both `any()` calls would return `TRUE` .

Answer (score 1):

Using `dplyr::rowwise()` and `c_across()` to compare your sets of columns, with an assist from `purrr::discard()` to drop `NA`s before comparing:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

dat %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(check = any(
    discard(c_across(contains("illness")), is.na) %in%
    discard(c_across(contains("DC")), is.na)
  )) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

```
# A tibble: 3 × 7
  illness_1 illness_2 ilnness_3   DC1   DC2   DC3 check
      <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <lgl>
1         1         4        NA    NA     1    98 TRUE 
2         2        NA         8    99    NA    97 FALSE
3        NA        NA        NA     2    NA    NA FALSE
```

*Example data:*

```
dat <- data.frame(
  illness_1 = c(1, 2, NA),
  illness_2 = c(4, NA, NA),
  ilnness_3 = c(NA, 8, NA),
  DC1 = c(NA, 99, 2),
  DC2 = c(1, NA, NA),
  DC3 = c(98, 97, NA)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

For all rows in a data frame `df` check if values in columns that contain *illness* intersect with values in columns that contain *DC*, excluding `NA`. Returning 1 or 0.

```
ill <- grepl("illness", colnames(df))
dc <- grepl("DC", colnames(df))

apply(df, 1, function(x) 
  (length(na.omit(intersect(as.numeric(unlist(x[ill])), 
                            as.numeric(unlist(x[dc]))))) > 0) * 1)
```